# Deleting home screens on Nexus 7 (2013) Android 5.1.1

Tags: screen

Does anyone know how to remove home screen on Nexus 7(2013)? I tried to long press an empty screen but there's only options to change the wallpaper. HELP

Comment: That functionality is provided only by a custom launcher. Which do you use? (Is it Google Now?)

Answer (score 2):

Answer on this depends on which launcher you're using; for this I'm assuming you're using [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) AKA Google Experience Launcher which should be the default.

All you need to do is remove all the icons and widgets that live on the home screen you wanna have removed. Once the homescreen become empty it will automatically be removed.

You can readd the screen by dragging an icon to the right edge of the right-most home screen you have an additional screen will be created.

The far-left Google Now screen cannot be removed though.

If you're using a different one than that let us know.